# Why won't the 'new comment' button appear in Google Docs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

When using Google Docs, either directly or through Google Classroom, the 'new comment' button does not appear after some users highlight text.

I use the appearance and function of this button in my Google Chrome Extension.

Users can highlight text then use the 'New Comment" button in the toolbar and a Comment bubble appears. But the button to add a comment, that usually appears on the right side of the document after highlighting, just doesn't show.

When I check the Developer Console I see the button but its opacity is set to 0:

```
<div id="docs-instant-button-bubble" class="docs-material docs-instant-button-bubble-transformation-ltr" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Add a comment" data-tooltip="Add a comment" style="top: 1511.4px; opacity: 0;" data-tooltip-suspended="true"><div class="docs-instant-button-bubble-icon-container"><span class="docs-instant-button-bubble-icon docos-icon-img docos-icon-img-hdpi docos-instant-icon-img docos-icon-instant-docos-ltr docos-instant-button-bubble-icon"></span></div></div>
```

Even if I turn the opacity to 1 the button (now visible) doesn't do anything when clicked.

Users have disabled all plugins etc. Other users at the organization do NOT have this issue. What could cause this effect in a Google Doc experience? 
Any help/suggestions for research appreciated.